# C++ program won't print command-line arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have decided to get back into programming (specifically C++) and to that end I have started working on a command-line parser. The goal is, eventually, to turn it into a simple class that I can import in some future projects.

This test program is simply supposed to list the number of arguments it received, then print them out, one per line, then exit.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    cout << "Es gibt " << argc << " Argumente." << endl;
    for(int i=0; i << argc; i++){
        cout << "Argument " << i << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what happens in the terminal:

```
[user@dx4320 cmdline-parser]$ g++ cmdline-parser-test.cpp -o parsetest
[user@dx4320 cmdline-parser]$ ./parsetest eins zwei
Es gibt 3 Argumente.
[user@dx4320 cmdline-parser]$
```

Why doesn't it print the arguments as it is supposed to? It clearly recognizes the arguments, so what is the problem? I'm sure I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: Change `i << argc` to `i < argc` and see if it doesn't work better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the wrong operator, you need:

```
for(int i=0; i < argc; i++){
   // only one ^ is correct here
```

otherwise you'd have the operator `<<` (aka "left shift") and as a result, the expression `i << argc` (where `i` is initially `0`) always evaluates to `false` and the loop's body is never executed.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked perfectly. It's been awhile since I've used C++. I have done more recent programming in java.

Comment: Err, wouldn't the bug be basically the same in Java?

Comment: @KG6ZVP if his solution works perfectly, why not designate it as "the solution"? That way we all know it's solved :)

Comment: @KG6ZVP It certainly did on my end, but I don't know about cluracan.